# mod_rewrite regexp

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on some rewrite rules, and for some reason a regexp I'm not expecting to pass (and does pass not on any of my regexp testers) is passing in mod_rewrite.

The URL in question is:

```
http://url.com/api/projects.json?division=aa
```

And the rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api\/([^.?#/%\s]+)\.([^#?\s]+)$ api.php?type=$1&format=$2 [NC,L]
```

Because the second capture is immediately followed by $ I'd expect that URL to fail because of the query string, but it seems to accept just fine and pass the two parameters to GET.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: Query String
>
> The Pattern will not be matched
>   against the query string. Instead, you
>   must use a RewriteCond with the
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variable.

Snip from the bottom of [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Cheers--so I'd just want to add a rewrite condition like: 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

Thanks pycruft.